# How to create/join vars in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to create a string for a configuration file.

It needs to be in this format:

```
nodes = ["node1","node2","node3"]
```

I was originally trying to do this by reading the hosts from a specific group in hosts, but decided it would be better to use a vars file.

in my vars file I have

```
---
nodes:
  - node: node1
  - node: node2
  - node: node3
```

I then want to use the lineinfile function to update the config:

```
- name: Update cluster nodes
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/nodes.txt
    regexp: '^#nodes:'
    line: "nodes: ["node1","node2","node3"]"
```

Can anyone help me as I am really struggling to get the string created after looping through the node list.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take advantage of the ["whitespace control" feature](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#whitespace-control) of jinja2 by leading and trailing the template with `{%-` and `-%}` to ensure any whitespace that is present for legibility to the playbook reader isn't carried through to the line. Then, you may find it convenient to move the line composition into a local `vars:` just for legibility:

```
- name: Update cluster nodes
  lineinfile:
    # ...as before
    line: 'nodes: [{{ nodes_csv }}]'
  vars:
    nodes_csv: >-
      {%- for n in nodes -%}
      {{ "" if loop.first else "," }}"{{ n }}"
      {%- endfor -%}
```

Depending on your specific needs, you may also just want to use the [`to_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) and then tell it to use separators without whitespace, since your example looks very much like JSON:

```
lineinfile:
  line: 'nodes: {{ nodes | to_json(separators=(",", ":")) }}'
```